# If getOrCreate is an antipattern, how can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, anti-patterns

According to http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html I believe getOrCreate function is an antipattern.

```
function getOrCreateObj(something) {
  let f = find(something, db); 
  if (f) return f;
  else return createObj(something);  
}
```

What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: You are creating a global variable `f` there. Better do that as, `find(something, db) || createObj(something)`. Apart from that, you have inconsistent `;` usage.

Comment: @thefourtheye that's true, it was only written without checking. But those are only details that don't have much to do with the question itself

Answer (score 2):

Better to have side-effect-free functions that return a specific type or null.

So you would have a `get` and a `create` method and in the application logic or an abstraction above that check for the existence of `something`

```
// pseudo code
get( INT: id ); // Returns SomeObj or NULL
create( INT:id ):: SomeObj;

// In service or application layer or other abstraction
foo = get( 1 ) || create( 1 );
```

Comment: well, but it does just the same as my code, I only scoped it under a function, didn't I?

Comment: It is another question, but let me answer it here: It *does* the same, but gives the caller more flexibility. It is called [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: @MaciejSz so the key is not to scope that funcitonality into one function, but always have it spread?

Comment: The idea is to write functions where you don't need to inspect the code to use. Side effects, even when commented, mean a programmer using the method needs to understand it's workings. In a complex system with hundreds of functions this can be too much to take in at once, and can radically slow a programmer down.